# PayPal dependency in play framework with scala

Tags: paypal, playframework, paypal-sandbox, playframework-2.1

I'm in trouble beacuse i don't know how to add *Paypal* Dependencies into my **Scala Playframework Application** Sbt.

Can anyone tell me how can i add this dependency ?

Comment: Can you point me to this artifact? Does it have a web site? Is it in a maven repository maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'*This dependency*' ? You mean [`paypal-core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk/paypal-core/1.5.2) ? It's on maven as you can see, so all you need is to copy artifact from SBT tab: `"com.paypal.sdk" % "paypal-core" % "1.5.2"` and add it to your `project/Build.scala` file as described in [Play doc in the ***Managed dependencies*** section](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTDependencies).

Don't forget to perform `play clean` `play update` and eventually `play yourIDE` after all